# How to replace first letters in string

Tags: python, regex

Given string as:

```
s = "python is programming language p"
```

I want get:

```
s = "2ython is 2rogramming language p"
```

So, i want to replace all letters "P/p", but only if words starts with it.

I've tried smth like this:

```
re.sub(r'(^p)*', r'/', string), but it didn't help
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\bp\B', '2', s, flags=re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SenIKl/1).

If you need to make sure there is a *letter* after `p` use

```
re.sub(r'\bp(?=[^\W\d_])', '2', s, flags=re.I)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SenIKl/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `p` - `p` or `P` (due to `re.I`)
- `\B` - a non-word boundary (next char must be a word char)
- `(?=[^\W\d_])` - a positive lookahead that requires any letter to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/hHWO4A):

```
import re
s = "python is programming language p"
print(re.sub(r'\bp(?=[^\W\d_])', '2', s, flags=re.I))
# => 2ython is 2rogramming language p
print(re.sub(r'\bp\B', '2', s, flags=re.I))
# => 2ython is 2rogramming language p
```